Taharah about the mattress
Assalmu alaikum
My question is concerning about me being in the state of impurity and about whether my bed is impure or not.
I was in a state impurity earlier and fell asleep last night, which was yesterday. Except no impurities got onto it. So my question, is my bed automatically impure even if no impurity is on.
Also, would it suffice or necessary to use air freshener to remove the smell of impurites even though there isn't at the moment.
